# How to inject mocked object into another already mocked object

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito

I have a class that I mocked like this:

```
@Mock
private MyClass1 mockMyClass1;
```

Say this class looks like that:

```
public class MyClass1 {
  @Autowired
  private MyInnerClass myInnerClass;
}
```

When I mock `MyClass1`, `MyInnerClass` will be initialized as `null`. Is it possible to initialize that private field with another mock objected? I want `myInnerClass` to be a mock like this one:

```
@Mock
private MyInnerClass myInnerClass;
```

If I use the following code:

```
@InjectMocks
private MyClass1 mockMyClass1;
@Mock
private MyInnerClass myInnerClass
```

This will initialize the private `MyInnerClass` inside `MyClass1` to be the mocked object, however this way `mockMyClass1` is not a mock itself any more, isn't it (I'm only injecting a mocked object inside a real class, just like `@Autowired` will inject a real object insite it)? Could you correct my logic if I'm wrong in my understanding of `@InjectMock` and `@Mock`? Also how could I inject a mocked object inside another mocked object (without using setters/constructors)?

Comment: You should be stubbing the behavior not the implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what a [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) is.

When you are mocking `MyClass1`, the inner field of type `MyInnerClass` doesn't exist anymore for the mocked object. As such, it doesn't make sense to try to inject something into a mock.

A mock is controlled by saying what it should do when you interact with it. You stub its public methods to do what you want them to do. You give behaviour. The only default behaviour (maybe specific to Mockito) is to return `null` if you didn't configure the mock (but do note that it doesn't return `null` because some internal variable is `null`, it returns that because Mockito decided that that's what it should return; maybe another mocking framework decided that it should throw an exception instead, who knows?).

As an example, consider that your real class is:

```
class MyClass1 {
    private MyInnerClass myInnerClass;
    public MyInnerClass getMyInnerClass() {
        return myInnerClass;
    }
}
```

Now consider `mock` a mock of that class. If you call `mock.getMyInnerClass()`, it is **not** the real method that is going to be called. What it will return is **not** the value of `myInnerClass`. It will return `null`, or if you have stubbed that method with

```
when(mock.getMyInnerClass()).thenReturn(something);
```

then it will return `something`.

So to answer your question: you can't do that because that's not how mocks work.

Comment: Sometimes it may make sense to put mock object into another mock object. For example if some class would use both MyClass1 and MyInnerClass instances and you wouldn't like to implement mock logic twice. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MateuszDryzek A mock class doesn't have the notion of a variable. It's gone. Poof. You only define behaviour for the mock. What it should do when you call its methods. The real code of the real class is no more.

Comment: @Tunaki I got to this problem because MyClass1 is a service layer class, which calls repository (database) layer methods (MyInnerClass is a repository layer class). I want to test MyClass1 logic, without actually interacting with the database layer (that's why I want MyInnerClass to be a mock). You made me realize a flow in my logic. At the moment I mock MyClass1 and then I do .thenCallRealMethod() on all the methods I'm interested to test. What I should probably do is mock MyInnerClass and inject it using InjectMock inside MyClass1.

Comment: @AntonBelev Yes, that's exactly what you should do and how mocks are supposed to be used :)!

Comment: @AntonBelev Well that makes me very happy :D

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really use InjectMocks annotation at all (to see why, you can read this [article](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/)).

You could just implement an Autowired constructor for MyClass1 instead of Autowired fields. Then you could simply pass your MyInnerClass mock reference as a constructor parameter.